# Sortable Js Laravel - How to save order of the created list?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sortablejs

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>
    <style>
        .list-group .list-group-item {
            border-radius: 0;
            cursor: move;
        }

        .list-group .list-group-item:hover {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
        }</style>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xl-10 order-2 order-sm-1 mt-3">
            <h2 class="h6"><strong>Sortable List</strong></h2>
            <div id="sortablelist" class="list-group mb-4 mt-3" data-id="1">
                <div class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" data-id="2">
                    <div>
                        <p class="mb-0 d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                            List Item 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" data-id="3">
                    <div>
                        <p class="mb-0 d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                            List Item 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script> new Sortable(sortablelist, {
        animation: 150,
        ghostClass: 'sortable-ghost'
    });</script>
```

I want to save the new order of the list, how do i do that?
Like send the data to a controller function as an array of ids

Thank you in advance!

Comment: HI.. did you find a way to do that? i have bene searching too and not a chance! thanks

Comment: @stoneshaq hello, I dont really remember how i fixed it but i can suggest a few ways that work. You can have a hidden input with an index array and just read it in the controller with the request.